# Display and replace fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am very new to Android development. I have an Activity (`LoginActivity`), which contains the background and the toolbar. Inside this activity I'd like to include two fragments.

The first one (login) is displayed when the activity starts, the second (sign-up) replaces the (login) fragment when a user clicks the register link.

My problem is that the (login) fragment isn't being shown when the activity starts. I am trying to do this by replacing a FrameLayout (`contentFragment`) with the login fragment, but it doesn't get replaced. No errors. It just seems as if the replacement code in `onCreate()` in `LoginActivity` isn't working

This is my attempt:

**LoginActivity Activity:**

```
package com.evently.pianomar.evently;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;

    private Button _loginButton, _test;
    private TextView _signupLink;
    private EditText _passwordText;
    private EditText _emailText;

    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mActionBarToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.contentFragment, fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**LoginFragment**

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_login.xml** (stripped down)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#e3e3e3"
    android:layout_weight="70">

 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What I've tried so far based on questions I read here without success:

- Remove FrameLayout from the LinearLayout in `activity_login`
- Make `LoginActivity` a FragmentActivity
- Use `.add()` instead of `.replace()` and Declare `fragment` in `LoginActivity` as `Fragment` instead of `LoginFragment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your problem is in **fragment_login.xml**:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
```

replace with:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

LoginFragment was loaded to FrameLayout, but it is just invisible.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the container as a null and it won't have a default container to replace.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, ***null***, false);
}
```

Then, when you call the method replace you can set the container by yourself. Here a sample:

```
myFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.myContainer, new MyFragment())
```

The "myContainer" part is the id for the view you have in your layout like a LinearLayout, RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.

Comment: Please provide a brief explanation of the code whenever you answer a question.